# Difficulties on displaying another full screen activity for alarm clock app

Tags: java, android

I'm a student learning programming in Android Studio and I met some difficulties when developing my Alarm clock project. I've done lots of experiments and research in my code but still I couldn't find the solution. I wanted to try to make a normal alarm that is when the alarm is activated, display another full screen activity to remind the user. I don't want my alarm app to just ring and toast notification. I want it to also display a screen.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.android.exno11;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.example.android.exno11.AlarmReceiver;
import com.example.android.exno11.R;

import java.util.Calendar;

import static android.R.id.message;
import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TimePicker alarmTimePicker;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    }    

    // Toggle button
    public void OnToggleClicked(View view) {
        long time;
        if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute() + 1);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

            time=(calendar.getTimeInMillis()-(calendar.getTimeInMillis()%60000));
            if(System.currentTimeMillis()>time) {    
                if (calendar.AM_PM == 0)
                    time = time + (1000*60*60*12);
                else
                    time = time + (1000*60*60*24);    
                }    
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, 120000, pendingIntent);
            }
            else {    
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);    
             }
        }
  }
```

And this is the manifest, not sure what I'm doing is right.Thank you for helping.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.exno11">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: for this i'd need to see the code of your `BroadcastReceiver`, your `Service` (if any) and your fullscreen `Activity`

Comment: also, your problem is that an activity should start but you see only a notification? or you did not program yet your activity to start ?